# Bind image to fileupload field on load

Tags: php, jquery, image-uploading

I'm working on a crud where I can upload student data including the profile photo.

My problem, is upon update, since not all fields are required. I'm receiving error saying `Undefined index: file` which is this line `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`.

So what I'm trying to achieve is load the image to the file upload field.

I can only display the file name but my problem is binding the image from its source to the field.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Upload Image:&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="input-group image-preview">
        <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled"> <!-- don't give a name === doesn't send on POST/GET -->
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" style="display:none;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear
            </button>
            <!-- image-preview-input -->
            <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                <span class="image-preview-input-title">Browse</span>
                <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="input-file-preview" id="uploadimage" /> <!-- rename it -->
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not pissible. Why uploading the same image again which was uploaded before? Just check, if another file was uploaded and then update the image table or the image column in your table. If no new image was uploaded, keep the old image.

Comment: The question says you are checking for `$_FILES['input-file-preview']`, but your question says your line is `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`. It is either one or the other. Please, fix your question.

Comment: @yivi sorry its a typo error

Comment: Not a problem. But edit your question so it makes sense. :)

Comment: Now you are using `file` in some places, and `fileToUpload`in other. And it doesn't match the HTML code, which is the base for my answer. Code posted should be as close as the real, working thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read [this](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php) carefully.

Basically you are checking `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]`, but in your HTML code you are referring to `name="input-file-preview"`

So your `$_FILES` index should be `input-file-preview`.

E.g. `$_FILES['input-file-preview']`;

Also, it is always a good idea to verify an array index exists before you use it.

E.g.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && array_key_exists($_FILES['fileToUpload']) ) {
   $target_dir = "uploads/";
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
   $uploadOk = 1;
   $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

   // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```